# onclick button not getting edit text string for api

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm developing a Calorie app using an API Database. When the user clicks the search button it gets the string and then searches the database. For some reason the user edit text "string" is not being retrieved therefore not being able to search the api database. When I did the debug I noticed that the string is "" meaning empty.

Thanks again so much, New to api and android studio.

```
  public class AddEntry extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {

   EditText FoodET,CalorieET;


   ImageButton Savebtn, Cancelbtn;
   Button searchbutton;

   String foodET,calorieET;


    //database
   private DatabaseHandler dba;


    public AddEntry() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_entry, container, 
    false);
   Savebtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
    Savebtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Savebtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    searchbutton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    searchbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Cancelbtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.CancelBtn);
    Cancelbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return myView;


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   FoodET= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);

    FoodET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    CalorieET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
    CalorieET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    foodET = ((EditText) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText)).getText().toString();
    foodET.isEmpty();
    FoodET.setText("");
    CalorieET.setText("");
    calorieET = ((EditText) 
   view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText)).getText().toString();

   }







         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.SearchButton:




            FoodSearch search = new FoodSearch(foodET,  CalorieET );

            search.execute();


            break;

        case R.id.SaveBtn:



            if (FoodET.getText().toString().equals(null) || 
           CalorieET.getText().toString().equals(null)||   
           CalorieET.getText().toString().equals("") || 
           CalorieET.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter information", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                AlertDialog NotFound = new
                        AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                NotFound.setTitle("Error");
                NotFound.setMessage("Food not found :(");
                NotFound.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
                       which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

            }
            else

            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);


            break;


        case R.id.CancelBtn:

           // EditText descriptionET= 
         (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);
          //descriptionET.setText("");


            //EditText calorieET= 
          (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
            //calorieET.setText("");

            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);

            break;
       }
    }

      @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach() {
     super.onDetach();
    }




   private class FoodSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String food;
    EditText calories;

    FoodSearch(String food, EditText calories){
        this.food = food;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            food = food.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?
         format=JSON&q=" + food +
                    "&max=1&offset=0&sort=r&api_
           key=xMJV33vSmKsquFqcBwZ23oJ7DlL2abmfsrDUUx1l");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
            url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                String result = stringBuilder.toString();
                if(result.contains("zero results")) {
                    String s = "empty";
                    return s;
                }
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new 
                JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
                JSONObject list = object.getJSONObject("list");
                JSONArray items = list.getJSONArray("item");
                String item = items.get(0).toString();
                int i = item.indexOf("ndbno\":\"") + 8;
                int f = item.indexOf("\"", i);
                String ndbno = item.substring(i,f);
                Log.d("DEBUG", ndbno);

                URL url2 = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?
               ndbno=" + ndbno +
                        "&type=b&format=JSON&api_
                 key=xMJV33vSmKsquFqcBwZ23oJ7DlL2abmfsrDUUx1l");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection2 = (HttpURLConnection) 
                url2.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(urlConnection2.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
                String line2;
                while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder2.append(line2).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader2.close();
                String res = stringBuilder2.toString();
                int index = res.indexOf("\"unit\": \"kcal\",") + 46;
                int index2 = res.indexOf("\"", index);
                String calories = res.substring(index,index2);
                urlConnection2.disconnect();
                return calories;
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            String s = "empty";
            return s;
        }
     }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("empty")) {
            calories.setText(response);
        } else {
            AlertDialog foodNotFound = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            foodNotFound.setTitle("Error");
            foodNotFound.setMessage("Food not found :(");
            foodNotFound.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int   
                          which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: By the way  `.equals(null)` is not how you check if something is null. And getText or toString never do return null for those objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
case  R.id.SearchButton:
           String foodEtString=FoodET.getText().toString();
            FoodSearch search = new FoodSearch(foodEtString,  CalorieET );
            search.execute();
            break;
```

And Add this in onCreate as well

```
 FoodET= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);
    FoodET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    CalorieET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
    CalorieET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null ob

Comment: awesome! it worked its displaying the value ! Dang man your a life savor

Comment: Thanks bro, happy coding and ask anything , anytime

Comment: You should go through fragment lifecycle for best knowledge

Comment: Those four lines in the second block are fine within onViewCreated

Answer (score 1):

Use these values instead when you go to execute the AsyncTask

```
String FoodName = FoodET.getText().toString().trim();
String calString = CalorieET.getText().toString().trim();
```

The following values are always empty when the view is created (and are not necessary in your code).

```
foodET = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText)).getText().toString();
calorieET = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText)).getText().toString();
```

So that explains why this didn't work

```
FoodSearch search = new FoodSearch(foodET,  CalorieET );
```

You should always try to call `getText` in response to a user event in order to get the most recent value(s) of the input fields

I'd also suggest that you learn how to properly parse JSON data (don't use indexOf), or go so far as look into the  Retrofit library

Comment: Those values go inside the onclick method.  Those values are from public void saveDataToDB () which I havent used